# Do seed nodes need less num_tokens than other nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cassandra cluster which is 21 nodes large and the seed node is one of the node whicg is seeing high disk usage, high memory usage and also services lot of connection. Currently the `num_tokens=256` and across all node.

My question is since seed nodes have the responsibility of processing the gossip info, do that need to take lesser data than the other nodes. Eg: keep `num_tokens=64` for seed nodes and `num_tokens=256` for other nodes. I could not find any information related to this. Does anyone have information.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of seed node is to bootstrap the gossiping process for the new nodes. Once the node has joined the cluster, seed node doesn't have much importance.

Your issue might be with the data model. Your data might have hot partitions and those hot partitions might be on the seed node which will cause more requests(reads/writes) on that specific node.

It is just a coincidence that the node is seed node.